# Is it possible to add a Reaction to a Microsoft Teams message?

Tags: python, python-3.x, botframework, chatbot, microsoft-teams

I have a Microsoft Teams bot with a message handler:

```py
async def on_message_activity(  # pylint: disable=unused-argument
    self, turn_context: TurnContext
):
    [...]
```

Lets say the bot receives a message and the bot wants to add a thumbsup reaction to it. I cannot find this in the documentation, is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, It is not supported for bot to add reactions to a message. You can raise a user voice [here](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/).

Answer (score -1):

While there isn't a current sample for adding reactions (closest thing to upvote/downvote I've seen) in python, there is a sample in C# and Node  in the botframework sample's repo [C# here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/25.message-reaction/Bots/MessageReactionBot.cs)

That being said, I'm not sure the  methods exist in python yet, but you can take a look at it to see what it does.

Comment: This code is possible in Python. The code detects when an user has added a reaction to a bot's message. However, I'd like the other way around; the bot adding a reaction to a message that was sent to the bot.