# `chatMessage: setReaction` API and Teams app/bot

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I am developing a app/bot for Microsoft Teams, in which I'd like to add reactions (thumbs up/down, etc) to users' message in a channel.

I am not using the Microsoft Graph API now, but it seems to be the only option if I want to [add reactions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chatmessage-setreaction?view=graph-rest-1.0) to users' messages.

However in the link above, it states that the access token required by this endpoint is not available for `Application`. It's only available for `Delegated` type.

In my case, my app/bot is an application running on its own server, which receives events from Microsoft Teams when the app/bot is mentioned in a chat. If the application access token is not usable here, I don't understand what kind of token I should retrieve to be able to call this endpoint.

Say if user "John Smith" sent a message and mentioned my bot, shall I obtain a delegated token (that John needs to grant) that calls APIs on behalf of John? If so and if the reaction is added, would it look like John added a reaction to his own message? Which feels super weird to me...

Answer (score 0):

You've kind of answered your own question - essentially, this permission combo (Delegated "Yes", Application "No") means that it's not actually possible to do what you're wanting to do. A bot can *receive* a reaction to a message it *sends*, but not *send* a reaction to a user's message. It's something people have raised elsewhere (e.g. [Is it possible to add a Reaction to a Microsoft Teams message?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66104696/is-it-possible-to-add-a-reaction-to-a-microsoft-teams-message) and https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-teams/adding-reaction-to-user-s-message-by-bot/m-p/3909357), but doesn't seem to be something Microsoft wants to offer, either via Graph of via the Bot Framework.